# Push one array as key, value to other array using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays like

```
var array1 = [{group_name: "Gp HQ, Hyderabad", group_id: "1"},
              {group_name: "Gp HQ, Secunderabad", group_id: "2"},
              {group_name: "Group HQ, Guntur", group_id: "3"}];


var array2 = [
  {unit_total: 1, branch_name: "1 (T) Air Sqn", branch_group_id: "1", branch_id: "6"},
  {unit_total: 1, branch_name: "1 (T) Arty Bty", branch_group_id: "1", branch_id: "5"},
  {unit_total: 3, branch_name: "1 (T) Bn", branch_group_id: "1", branch_id: "1"}, 
  {unit_total: 1, branch_name: "1 (T) R&V Regt", branch_group_id: "1", branch_id: "4"},
  {unit_total: 3, branch_name: "3 (T) Bn", branch_group_id: "1", branch_id: "2"}];
```

Here array2 is multilevel array, next value will contain group_id 2 as follows

I want to push array2 value to array1 with key name like below

```
var result_array = [{group_id:1, group_name:test_group, child_array:[
                     {unit_total: 1, branch_name: "1 (T) Air Sqn", branch_group_id: "1", branch_id: "6"},
                     {unit_total: 1, branch_name: "1 (T) Arty Bty", branch_group_id: "1", branch_id: "5"},
                     {unit_total: 3, branch_name: "1 (T) Bn", branch_group_id: "1", branch_id: "1"}, 
                     {unit_total: 1, branch_name: "1 (T) R&V Regt", branch_group_id: "1", branch_id: "4"},
                     {unit_total: 3, branch_name: "3 (T) Bn", branch_group_id: "1", branch_id: "2"}},

                    {group_id:2, group_name:test_group, child_array:[
                     {unit_total: 1, branch_name: "1 (T) Air Sqn", branch_group_id: "2", branch_id: "6"},
                     {unit_total: 1, branch_name: "1 (T) Arty Bty", branch_group_id: "2", branch_id: "5"},
                     {unit_total: 3, branch_name: "1 (T) Bn", branch_group_id: "2", branch_id: "1"}, 
                     {unit_total: 1, branch_name: "1 (T) R&V Regt", branch_group_id: "2", branch_id: "4"},
                     {unit_total: 3, branch_name: "3 (T) Bn", branch_group_id: "2", branch_id: "2"}}
```

]];

How can i achieve this. I have tried using array_push and concat methods also but no luck.
Please let me know how to do this. Thanks in advance

Comment: `array1` is invalid

Comment: can you please let me know, why above arrays are invalid?

Comment: @user3668438 because arrays look like [1,2,3] not [key:value, key:value]

Comment: Missing brackets around objects in array. It should be `var array1 = [{group_id:1}, {group_name:test_group}];` See, how is it different from `array2`

Comment: are you sure array1 is meant to be an array? given the names of the keys, array1 looks like it'd be better served as an object. `{group_id: 1, group_name: 'test_group', child_array: [...]}`

Comment: added my actual array, please check

Comment: Please post correct result as well.

Comment: Please amend your expected result as `result_array` is not a valid array

Comment: Please check array, i have corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through array1 and use array.filter to populate child_array:

```js
var array1 = [ 
  { group_id: "1", group_name: 'test_group1' },
  { group_id: "2", group_name: 'test_group1' }
];

var array2 = [
  {unit_total: 1, branch_name: "1 (T) Air Sqn", branch_group_id: "1", branch_id: "6"},
  {unit_total: 1, branch_name: "1 (T) Arty Bty", branch_group_id: "1", branch_id: "5"},
  {unit_total: 3, branch_name: "1 (T) Bn", branch_group_id: "2", branch_id: "1"}, 
  {unit_total: 1, branch_name: "1 (T) R&V Regt", branch_group_id: "1", branch_id: "4"},
  {unit_total: 3, branch_name: "3 (T) Bn", branch_group_id: "2", branch_id: "2"}];
  
array1.forEach(group => group.child_array = array2.filter(e => e.branch_group_id === group.group_id));

console.log(array1);
```